# Using external type declarations with OCamlyacc

Tags: ocaml, parser-generator, ocamlyacc

I have a type expr in an expr.ml file. In parser.mly (OCamlyacc file), I define the expr rule and give the type :

```
    %start expr
    %type <expr> expr
```

However, I get :

```
    File "parser.mli", line 34, characters 48-52:
    Error: Unbound type constructor expr
```

I tried adding

```
    %{
      open Expr
    %}
```

at the beginning of the .mly file but it still doesn't work. How may I define this expr type in an external file and use it as the return value of my rule? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to qualify `expr` type with the module name. I.e., if it is defined in `expression.ml` (using `type expr = ...`) you should use

```
%type <Expresssion.expr> main
```

Note the capital `E` when using the module name.

Answer (score 2):

I"m not sure if I'm understanding correctly.

But you are struggling with a circular dependency? Let's say `T` contains your type and calls the parser, `P`. `P` cannot produce type `T.t` since `T` depends on `P`, not the other way around. Normally, I've created a third file that contains the type information, `T'`.

For example,

T.ml

```
 let parse filename : T'.t =
     filename
         |> open_in
         |> Lexing.from_channel
         |> P.command L.token
```

P.mly

```
%type <T'.t> command
%start command
%%
```

T'.ml

```
type t = Label of String
       | Integer of String
       | Float of string
       | Star of t
```

Answer (score 1):

Ocamlyacc doesn't let you specify text to be generated in the interface (`.mli`) file. So wherever you specify a type that goes into the interface (the type of a token or rule), you need to use a fully-qualified type.

Here it looks like you can use a fully-qualified type, but sometimes that's not possible because the type involves a functor application. There are several workarounds:

- Arrange to build all functors in a separate compilation unit. This is easy, but doesn't work e.g. if the functors involve the token type.
- Do post-processing on the ocamlyacc-generated `.mli` file to add a header. You can do pretty much anything this way, but it's ugly and annoying.
- Use [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/), an improved replacement of Ocamlyacc. It's an additional dependency, but it does solve Ocamlyacc's main shortcomings.